# changing marginTop via javascript doesnt work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I have a problem, basicly it looks like this on Chrome:

[image]

but like this on Firefox:

[image]

I use this code snippet to set it like that:

```
document.getElementById('jackpot').style.marginTop = "-470px";
```

The thing is, when I switch it to a positive value it actually works (gets pushed more to the bottom), but somehow not in the negative values. w3c school says the marginTop tag should work for every browser.

Comment: you should give out more information about what problem you work on. Only one css line does not show any problem

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: did you empty your cache before testing? test in private/incognito mode if you don't want to care about that

Comment: @loli well i see the change when I do it in positive, so i dont think its the cache.

Comment: @humble.rumble I pretty much have to do it this way, since I calculate how much exactly is needed to close the gap. Heres the code:http://pastebin.com/c0nr3NTw

Answer (score -1):

Well, I prefer you should use jQuery because jQuery has cross browser compatibility unlike JavaScript and its easy to use !

```
$("#jackpot").css("margin-top","-470px");
```